# Increasing and decreasing function doubt

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

This is a question of increasing and decreasing functions.

$f(x)=\sin x + \cos x$, $x$ belongs to $[0, 2\pi]$

Derivative of this function $f'(x) = \cos x - \sin x$

For increasing function we put $f'(x) > 0$.

I tried to solve it this way:

$\cos x - \sin x > 0$

$\cos x > \sin x$

$\tan x < 1$

$x$ belongs to $\left(0, \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)\cup \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{5\pi}{4}\right) \cup \left(\dfrac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi\right)$

But the answer given in the book is $x$ belongs to $\left(0, \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)\cup \left(\dfrac{5\pi}{4}, 2\pi\right)$.

Any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you did up to$$\cos x>\sin x\tag1$$is fine. After this point, you need to consider two possibilities:

- $x\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)\cup\left(\frac{3\pi}2,2\pi\right)$: then $\cos x>0$ and what you did is fine;
- $x\in\left(\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2\right)$: then $\cos x<0$ and what you deduce from $(1)$ is that $\tan x>1$.

  ---

  Another possibility is to use the fact that\begin{align}\cos(x)+\sin(x)&=\sqrt2\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)\cos(x)+\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)\sin(x)\right)\\&=\sqrt2\cos\left(x-\frac\pi 4\right).\end{align}Since you know where $\cos$ is increasing and decreasing…

Comment: What will be the steps to solve this way? Can you provide some details, please?

Comment: @ShekharMalhotra If  $a > b$ and $b> 0$ then $\frac a b > 1$.  If  $a > b$ and $b< 0$ then $\frac a b < 1$

Comment: In $\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)$, $\tan x<1\iff x\in\left(0,\frac\pi4\right)$. In $\left(\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2\right)$, $\tan x>1\iff x\in\left(\frac{5\pi}4,\frac{3\pi}2\right)$. Finally, in $\left(\frac{3\pi}2,2\pi\right)$, $\tan x$ is always negative and, in particular, it is smaller than $1$. So, the answer is$$\left(0,\frac\pi4\right)\cup\left(\frac{5\pi}4,2\pi\right).$$

Comment: You need to verify the point $x = \dfrac{3\pi}{2}$ separately. $$\cos \dfrac{3\pi}{2} = 0, \sin \dfrac{3\pi}{2} = -1$$ so $\cos x > \sin x$ at that point, as well.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Sure. You are right.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos OK. I have another question. The book has excluded x = 0, 2π and you have also excluded x = 0, 2π, but at x = 0 and 2π, cos x is greater than sin x, so, the solution set should be, x belongs to [0, π/4)U(5π/4, 2π]?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: My steps are **[1] 1st quadrant** - : $sin x, cos x$ both positive $cos x – sin x > 0$ then $1 – tan x > 0$ then $tan x < 1$ **[2] 2nd quadrant**: $sin x$ is positive, $cos x$ negative, $-cos x – sin x > 0$ (take – sign out to make the term positive) $tan x > -1$ **[3] 3rd quadrant** : $sin x, cos x$ both negative, $-cos x + sin x > 0$ (take – sign out to make the term positive) $tan x > 1$ **[4] 4th quadrant** : cos x positive, sin x negative, $cos x + sin x > 0$ (take – sign out to make the term positive) $tan x > -1$ Kindly correct where am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are right about the extreme points: $0$ and $2\pi$ are also solutions.

Comment: What you did in the next comment is wrong. For instance, in the second quadrant, the inequality $\cos x-\sin x>0$ doesn't become $\cos x-\sin x>0$ just because $\cos x$ is negative. It always remains $\cos x-\sin x>0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: OK. One more question.  For increasing functions we put $f′(x)>0$. But, this is for strictly increasing functions. **Question says that find the intervals in which the function is increasing or decreasing**.  This means we can put $f'(x)>=0$. If we put the condition this way, $π/4$ and $5π/4$ will also be the part of the solution. Am I correct?

Comment: @ShekharMalhotra Yes, you are correct.